# How can i align textview by center horizontal

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, textview

I have created this xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="11" >
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/tabs_color">
    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="start|center"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/returnButton" 
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_menu_back_selector"/>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
       android:background="@color/black"
       android:layout_gravity="center|center"
       android:layout_width="180dp" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
       android:textColor="@color/white">
    </TextView>
       </LinearLayout>
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:fillViewport="true" />
<FrameLayout
    android:background="@color/tabs_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button_selector"
        android:id="@+id/OptionsButton"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"/>
      <Button
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_button_selector"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/AddItemButton"/>
      </FrameLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

But as result i have textview left aligned just right behind button returnButton

So i get my textview position is like: 
returnButtonTextView..................
and i want like: 
returnButton......TextView............

And this is not works too:

```
((TextView) listname).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Just a recommendation, where you want to make a complex layout try using RelativeLayout it gives you much more flexibility

Comment: Did you try my answer...? You should try it and tell me. I answered first... :/

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `RelativeLayout` rather than `LinearLayout` if you need more flexibility when creating layouts.

**Replace**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/tabs_color">

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="start|center"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/returnButton"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_menu_back_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**with**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/tabs_color">

    <Button
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/returnButton"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_menu_back_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/tabs_color">
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="start|center"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/returnButton"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_menu_back_selector"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```